# How can I test whether there were errors in PowerShell when I build a VS solution?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I have the following PowerShell script for building a VS solution.  This works, however, what I need to test is whether the build succeeded or failed.  How can I tell if the build failed or not from within the PS script?

**CODE**

```
[string] $res = $null
$log          = "buildlog.txt" 
$DevenvExe    = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe'
$MsBuildExe   = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'
$SolutionPath = ".\MyLocalSolution.sln"

#... There's some code here...

###########################
# BRANCH - ATTEMPT COMPILE
###########################

$res = & $DevenvExe $SolutionPath /upgrade /out $res
LogError

$res = & $MsBuildExe $SolutionPath /p:Configuration=Release /nr:false /m:4
LogError
```

**NOTE**: `LogError` is a function that checks the $res value.  If $res is empty, it's considered there isn't an error.  This is setup for some commands that happen above the build.  Of course, I can change how the building process checks for errors.  In fact, that's what I'm asking.  Currently `$res` is filled with successful build details.  I'd rather find a way to check and see if there were any build errors.

Comment: `$LASTEXITCODE` contains the exit code of the last program you ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `$LASTEXITCODE` for a suitable exit code. Typically this will be `0` on success.

```
$res = & $DevEnvExe $arguments
if ( $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 ) {
  LogError
}

$res = & $MsBuildExe $arguments
if( $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 ) {
  LogError
}
```

This can be extended to check the result of *any* program run from Powershell, not just `devenv` or `msbuild`. Though you will need to understand which exit codes mean success, warnings, or other conditions you may still want to consider a success.

Comment: Thank you.  Will test when I get back to my desk.